# working and integrating paypal payment pro

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have worked with paypal standard, but the documentation for paypal payment pro is quite vague and I am not sure how to be address it. For you're information, this is PayPal Pro:

https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Now I did search around, and came accross this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php--net-25397

but its quite outdated, and I am not sure it's relevancy. The other thing is that this tutorial only deals with credit card payments, I would like to understand and have the whole workflow.

I am quite lost, and would need guidance, if any examples on github are found or any support provided I would appreciated. I am quite accustom with javascript and php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually the writer of that tutorial.  :)  It is till relevant and works just fine if you follow those procedures.

Payments Pro is just for credit cards.  You don't need Pro for other APIs, so if you're just trying to work with Express Checkout you don't need Pro.

Either way, I would recommend grabbing this [PayPal PHP library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It makes all of the API calls very simple for you, and it's consistently maintained and up to date.  PayPal's own integration team has been using and recommending it as well.

Using that library, you would use the DoDirectPayment sample/template to process credit cards directly on the site.

For PayPal payments you would use Express Checkout which consists of SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment (in that order.)

You can see [fully functional samples/demos here](http://paypalphp-sandbox.angelleye.com) that use the same library.